# How can make folder with Firebase Cloud Functions Storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

**how can I make folder "posts" ?**

> bucket --> gs://app.appspot.com/posts

**code**

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object()
  .onChange(event => {
    const object = event.data
    const filePath = object.name
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop()
    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
    const tempFilePath = `/posts/${fileName}`

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tempFilePath
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath)
      return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '400x400>', tempFilePath])
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('thumbnail created')
      // match end of string that contains a slash followed by 0 or more characters that are not a slash:
      const thumbFilePath = filePath.replace(/(\/)?([^\/]*)*/, '$1thumb_$2')
          console.log('afoter=thumbFilePath=='+thumbFilePath);
      return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
        destination: thumbFilePath
      })
    })

  });
```

**error**

> Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open  '/posts/image.jpg'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cloud Functions has a read-only filesystem except for the `/tmp` directory. You need to make your `/posts` directory something like `/tmp/posts` to be able to create directories or write. You could also use something like [node-tmp](https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp) to manage the creation of temp files/dirs more easily.

Comment: Wow, i was just banging my head against the wall trying to write to the DB on a cloud function. Thanks for clarifying, not sure where that is even mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Also, to make sure your code is portable, don't hard-code "tmp" use os.tmpdir() to get the local temporary directory and use path.join() to get subpaths. This makes sure that your node modules work on Windows, which comes in handy when someone wants to test your code using the local emulator.

Comment: Hitting my head for one whole day and ended up here. Thank you!

Comment: Under what circumstances is the /tmp directory wiped out? Inactivity, new deployment, etc. Thanks.

Comment: You should never make assumptions that the `/tmp` directory will survive beyond the current event you're processing.

Comment: @ThomasBouldin Thank you. os.tempdir() is an excellent solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

**working code like the following:**

```
//add 3 package
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');


exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object()
  .onChange(event => {

  const object = event.data; 
  const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
  const filePath = object.name; 
  const contentType = object.contentType; 
  const resourceState = object.resourceState; 
  const metageneration = object.metageneration; 

  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  return bucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
    // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '400x400>', tempFilePath]);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
    // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
    const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
    const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
    // Uploading the thumbnail.
    return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {destination: thumbFilePath});
  // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
  }).then(() => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath));

  });
```

> Successful   -> /tmp/posts -> gs://app.appspot.com/posts