# read video from storage and send it to model ML kit in Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Hoping you are all good. My team have a problem in our Graduation project .

we are converting any video that's send from android application to text .

any video uploaded to Firebase storage and we had finished our model ML in TensorFlow .

we tried to read video from storage in function cloud to send the video to model ,but we couldn't find any resources .

in last Try, our function code was like :

```
exports.readVideo = functions.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), object.name);
    console.log(tempFilePath);
    console.log('download');
    // note download
    await bucket
        .file(object.name!)
        .download({
            destination: tempFilePath,
        })
        .then()
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log({
                type: 'download',
                err: err,
            });
        });
    console.log('read');
    // note read
    let stream = await bucket
        .file(object.name!)
        .createReadStream({
            start: 10000,
            end: 20000,
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('error 1');
            console.log({ error: err });
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(object.name));
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.on('finish', resolve);
        console.log('error 3');
        stream.on('error', reject);
    });

    console.log('tempFile size2', fs.statSync(tempFilePath).size);­­­

    return fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
});
```

and there's an error log in error3 line :

Error:EROFS:read-only file system,open'zoom_0.mp4'.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read and search.

Comment: thank's , I fix it .

Comment: The error looks very similar to the one on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849554/how-can-make-folder-with-firebase-cloud-functions-storage) . Does the discussion there help you to solve your issue?